# How to use variables in txt file in my batch file

Tags: file, batch-file

I have a txt file naemd as (settings.txt )which has content

```
SET BACKUP_DRIVE=E:\
SET BACKUP_DIRECTORY=BACKUP\
SET HOURLY_DIRECTORY=HOURLY\
SET INPUT_DIRECTORY=D:\MySQL\Data\CDR\.
```

I have a bat file where I want to use these variables for prepare backup path

```
SET BACKUP_PATH=%BACKUP_DRIVE%%BACKUP_DIRECTORY%%HOURLY_DIRECTORY%%CURRENT_HOUR%\
```

But I am not getting prepared path.

I have tried 
type settings.txt in the bat file
It is printing content of setting file but not implementing it..showing echo is off..
if I do echo on then some prob also.
Please tell me how to use these variables

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
@echo off&setlocal
:: set CURRENT_HOUR for testing
set "CURRENT_HOUR=03"
for /f "delims=" %%i in (settings.txt) do %%i
SET "BACKUP_PATH=%BACKUP_DRIVE%%BACKUP_DIRECTORY%%HOURLY_DIRECTORY%%CURRENT_HOUR%\"
echo %BACKUP_PATH%
```

Output is:

```
E:\BACKUP\HOURLY\03\
```

Comment: hey thanks for your reply dear, what about SET INPUT_DIRECTORY=D:\MySQL\Data\CDR\

Comment: You can use it: `echo %INPUT_DIRECTORY%` or destroy it `set "INPUT_DIRECTORY="`, don't worry :)

Comment: yes..that has been done..but i am facing one problem,when I have set path E:\BACKUP\HOURLY\03\ later on......i am using XCopy %INPUT_DIRECTORY%accountdetails.*  %BACKUP_PATH%CDR /D /E /C /I /Q /Y  which should  CDR in "E:\BACKUP\HOURLY\03\"...but it is not adding..it simple making a folder at E:\BACKUP\HOURLY\ named as 03 and and CDR BT CDR Should be in 03...pls help me in this also

Comment: This does work for me here: `XCopy "%INPUT_DIRECTORY%accountdetails.*" "%BACKUP_PATH%CDR" /D /E /C /I /Q /Y `. This makes `E:\BACKUP\HOURLY\03\CDR` and puts all `accountdetails.*` in the `CDR` folder!

Comment: ok,let me try at my side also now. Thanks for your quick responses.